# Coloring text with css using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I have a little problem adding a class to a span element and so coloring it in order to perform simple validation.

Here is my js:

```
     function validateKey(){
        var length = $('#appkey').val().length; 
        if(length != 8){
            $('#appkey').addClass('error');
            $('#appKeyInfo').addClass('error');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#appkey').removeClass('error');
            $('#appKeyInfo').removeClass('error');
            return true;
        }
      }
```

And html:

```
<label>KEY</label></br>
<input type="text" id="appkey" value=""/></br>
<span id="appKeyInfo">Dein App-Key aus 8 Ziffern</span>
```

And the jsfiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gk5CG/)

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** coloring of appKeyInfo fails, coloring appkey works. When I remove color:red and type font-weight:bold instead the text is bold on error. when I remove color definition of appKeyInfo the text can be colored red on error, strange thing, but I need a font color for the appKeyInfo

Comment: Works for me in FX - what is the issue exactly?

Comment: Is your CSS class for .error targeting only #appKey, or perhaps only input boxes?

Comment: i updated my answer, #appKeyInfo keeps grey, strange thing

Comment: The box goes pink in safari. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: well the input field gets red, but the span keeps grey

Comment: I think your CSS classes are in the wrong order.  You have a definition for span.error followed by span#appKeyInfo which overwrites the CSS rule.

Comment: hm I copied it at the end of the css file but still the same result

Comment: very strange:D changing color:red to font-weight:bold produces bold text on error...but color:red; has now effect

Comment: Well at least you've ruled out that it wasn't a jQuery error, so you should update the question :)  Try adding span#appKeyInfo.error to be explicit and see if that works, then work backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration for `span#appKeyInfo` takes precedence since it is an id you are styling.
 Try using `color:red !important` to force the override

**Edit**

Just a note, you can use multiple selectors in your jQuery. Like this:

```
$('#appkey', '#appKeyInfo').removeClass('error');
```

Answer (score 0):

your comparison operator is wrong, use less than operator :

```
  function validateKey(){
    var length = $('#appkey').val().length;    
    if(length < 8){
        $('#appkey').addClass('error');
        $('#appKeyInfo').addClass('error');
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#appkey').removeClass('error');
        $('#appKeyInfo').removeClass('error');
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry but I exactly 8 chars are required. this question is about the coloring!